# Regex error ISBN 10

Tags: php, regex

i have the following regular expression to use for ISBN-10

```
^[0-9]{9}[[0-9]|X|x]$^
```

it seems to work fine with all numbers, however when letters are introduced it gives me the letter instead, example ISBN 047146158X returns X in the array,

can someone help me with my expression?

this is what the data looks like

```
startISBN 10-047146158X Author(s): Stephen R. Bolsover, Jeremy S. Hyams, Elizabeth A. Shephard, Hugh A. White, Claudia G. Wiedemann Publisher- Wiley 27 JAN 2004
```

Comment: `[[0-9]|X|x]` -- you probably meant `[\dXx]`, didn't you? PS: could you add a **complete** code with the original string defined and `preg_match` part?

Comment: Did you mean a normal group for the second part, i.e. `^[0-9]{9}([0-9]|X|x)$`?

Comment: what is your input is it `ISBN 047146158X`?

Comment: posted what the data looks like when called echoed,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either

```
[0-9]{9}([0-9]|X|x)
```

or just

```
[0-9]{9}[0-9Xx]
```

The `[]` brackets match a single character inside them, nesting them doesn't do what you want.  Parentheses `()` mark a group where you can use the `|` character to separate different options, but since you're looking for one character only you can just put everything in brackets.

`^` means "start of line" and `$` means "end of line" - if you have them at the start and at the end, the regex matches *only* if there's nothing else in the input.

Comment: actually it didn't work :/ this is what the data looks like when its called from the database startISBN 10-047146158X Author(s): Stephen R. Bolsover, Jeremy S. Hyams, Elizabeth A. Shephard, Hugh A. White, Claudia G. Wiedemann Publisher- Wiley 27 JAN 2004

Comment: Ok, just remove the `^` and `$` characters from the start and the end.

Answer (score 1):

try this pattern

```
\b[0-9]{9}[0-9Xx]\b
```